# cfmail rejecting style statements

Tags: coldfusion, styles, lucee, cfmail

For some time I've had code that looks like this:

```
<cfmail
          from     = "#session.user#"  
          to       = "#PersonEmail1#"          
          password = "#session.password#"
          username = "#session.user#"       
          server   = "localhost"                            
          replyto  = "#session.user#"
          subject  = "#txt['repsubject']#"               
          type     = "html"   >   
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
     .repbordtop {
      border-top:5px double #A56ABD;
      color: #630D85;
      padding-top: 2px;
   }

</style>
</head>
</html>
   stuff
</cfmail>
```

I was running it both in Lucee and in ColdFusion 10 and it was working.  Occasionally the formatted 'stuff' even came through formatted.

Now, suddenly, it is throwing errors in both Lucee and ColdFusion.  In particular it refuses to recognize the style statement.  In Lucee I get

missing terminating [#] for expression
Stacktrace  The Error Occurred in
/opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/reports/frag3.cfm: line 25

```
23:
24: .repbordtop {
25: border-top:5px double #A56ABD;
26: color: #630D85;
27: padding-top: 2px;
```

whereas in ColdFusion I get:

Invalid CFML construct found on line 25 at column 35.
ColdFusion was looking at the following text:

;

The CFML compiler was processing:

```
An expression that began on line 25, column 28.
The expression might be missing an ending #, for example, #expr instead of #expr#.
The body of a cfmail tag beginning on line 9, column 3.
```

The error occurred in /home/moxwareo/public_html/reports/frag3.cfm: line 25

```
23 : 
24 :    .repbordtop {
25 :      border-top:5px double #A56ABD;
26 :      color: #630D85;
27 :      padding-top: 2px;
```

So it's choking on the same line, and clearly the style tag is not being recognized.

The code I've shown above is what I used to test the problem. I have checked my code in the real program against what I was using when it was working, and there is no difference.

Does anyone have some insight into why the style tag is suddenly not being recognized?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the # signs in the CSS? If it's inside a `cf` tag, I think you have to.

Comment: What was changed?

Comment: TRose, I've tried it both with and without the extra # -- it makes no difference.

Comment: Ageax, the changes I made were in the area I called "stuff".  But the program I wrote above is the one I used to test (without the "stuff" line).  It's hard to imagine that a change below the  end style tag would make any difference.

Comment: Did you try it with two #.s. Also try using named colors to see if that works

Comment: @BettyMock You may as well wrap the whole thing in a try/catch block if you haven't already. You might get a more verbose error message to work with, if you believe it's not the # issue.

Comment: Well, I re-instated an old version which was working, and it is still working.  So I made the fixes needed in the new version, and it is still working.  This will remain an mystery.  TRose, the try/catch idea is a good one, and I will use it when this kind of thing happens again.

Answer (score 4):

The cfmail body is evaluated just like being wrapped in cfoutput. The hash marks are being seen as the start of a variable/expression to be interpreted and output. To escape `#` you need to double it `##`.

Comment: I have used double ##.  It does not make the error go away.  The ## would be used if you have a style = statement within a tag like <p or <td.  However, within a <style> tag it is like creating a style sheet, and the second # is not needed -- indeed it gets in the way.

Comment: "within a <style> tag ... the second # is not needed" ... Uh, if the <style> tag is wrapped in `cfoutput` or any other such tag, it's super needed.

Comment: @BettyMock to be super clear about it... all you are doing is building up a big string. CF and the cfmail tag have no concept of style tags. They are just compiling a string that becomes the content of the message.

Comment: Dan, This does not explain why I am getting an error.

Comment: Humor us. Double up all your # signs in the CSS. Wrap it in a `cftry` and `cfcatch` and dump the `cfcatch`. If you get the same error message I'd be shocked.

Comment: TRose, since I've solved the problem by going back to an earlier version, I'm going to skip the try/catch for now.  But I like the idea of using it to track down other obscure errors.  If I were still stuck I would definitely humor you.